# addTarget is not working for button in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

When I m clicking on button , selector is not getting called.
There are only two component is the cell , 1 is image and another is UIButton. 
Below is the code for collection cell. is there any other way to add method.

```
class AttachmentCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   weak var delegate: AttachmentCellDelegate?

let removeButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "close_icon"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return button
}()

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imgView = UIImageView()
    imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    imgView.clipsToBounds = true
    return imgView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    self.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.contentView.addSubview(removeButton)
    //self.addSubview(removeButton)

    imageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.leading.equalToSuperview()
        make.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        make.top.equalToSuperview()
        make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
    }

    removeButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(40)
        make.height.equalTo(40)
        make.top.equalTo(imageView.snp.top).offset(-5)
        make.trailing.equalTo(self.imageView.snp.trailing).offset(5)
    }

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}

  @objc func removeButtonTapped() {
     delegate?.didRemoveButtonTapped()
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t even compile

Comment: Sorry vadian it wont. It needs snapKit library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `let removeButton` to `lazy var removeButton`.

`self` doesn't exist until `init` has been called. When you add a target to `self` in a `let` constant, you are defining it before `init` has been called.

Alternatively, just call `addTarget` in the `init` block.